# Set imported certificate to always be trusted in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ssl

I have generated a certificate in pfx format in Mac os X and imported it into system keychain using:

```
sudo security import server.pfx -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain -P foobar
```

The problem is that all trusts are set to `no value specified`.

[image]

How can I set trust for code signing to `Always trust` using **command line**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-p` option may be what you need. It can be specified more than once for each of the settings. I wish I knew how to deny one specific item while trusting another all in the same line.

`sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -p [option] -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <certificate>`

-p options are `ssl, smime, codeSign, IPSec, iChat, basic, swUpdate, pkgSign, pkinitClient, pkinitServer, timestamping, eap`

Comment: trustRoot should be trustAsRoot for -r parameter, or you'll get an error says "SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings: One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid."

Comment: Wonder if trustRoot v. trustAsRoot is a recent update?

Answer (score 11):

Here's what worked for me, it's very close  to that traveling beard's answer.  I'm using `trustAsRoot` instead of `trustRoot`.

With this change, in the Keychain Viewer, my cert now has "Always Trust" set.  When I used `trustRoot`, the cert is added but with "Use System Default" set and the system default is to Never Trust.

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustAsRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <certfile>
```

NOTE: The `sudo` will prompt for a password on the commandline and the gui will also prompt.

Nice, now I can import a dev cert on the command line with only a sudo passwd and not have to open that GUI!!